# The member "Height" is not recognized or is not accessible

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, material-design

I want to set the Height property in a setter of a style but it shows the error at design time. It will work without problem at runtine.

The type inherits from control, which inherits for framework element, that has a Height property.

Can someone explain why and how I can fix it or get rid of the message?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type materialDesign:PackIcon}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type materialDesign:PackIcon}}">
    <Setter Property="Height"
            Value="30" />
</Style>
```

<s>I think it has nothing to do with the class itself, but here is the code anyway:</s>
Apparently it has to do with the class itself:
[materialDesign:PackIcon](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/a7ff39437a5e43b2038afa0b02106d06ff28af9c/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/PackIcon.cs)

---

Edit1:

After prefixing with FrameworkElement I get the error messagages:

> PackIconExtension' type must derive from FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement.

and

> The resource "materialDesign:PackIcon" could not be resolved.

Seemingly it is an extension - but this surpasses my wpf knowledge.

```
<Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Height"                                             
        Value="30" />
```

---

Edit2:

Here is the code of the extension: [materialDesign:PackIconExtension](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/2740f14a814896d42032ae0013b765a8a0ec04c3/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/PackIconExtension.cs)

Comment: Did you try to restart Visual Studio? This sometimes work wonders for designer issues. If it works as expected at runtime, it's clearly a designer thing.

Comment: Also, rebuilding solves some designer issues sometimes.

Comment: Yes - I tried all the usual stuff: Clean/Rebuild, restart of vs and deleting of binarys

Comment: I got used to these kind of errors and care no more for the design errors. I noticed that if you open your project with Blend they disappear (only in Blend of course) so it's probably some limitation of Visual Studio xaml design rendering. Also while using Rider i have almost no error of this kind.

Comment: Kind of frustrating - but thanks for the info. The problem is that the design view does not work any more.

Comment: I ended up defining a resource:

<System:Double x:Key="PackIconSize">40</System:Double> ...

<materialDesign:PackIcon Height="DynamicResource PackIconSize}"/>